# Python 3: Spotify Add Song To Public Playlist

Tags: python, flask, localhost, spotify, python-3.4

So currently I have in place a system using [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/python3/) running on my localhost:8080 to add 1 song at a time to a public Spotify playlist. Unfortunately how I have implemented this it requires a browser to add a song. What I want to be able to do is URLLIB or possibly the REQUESTS library to do this without a browser. I have been unsuccessful in my attempts to do this bot URLLIB and REQUESTS only see the first page of my local host it is never redirected to my call back in the code that I linked below.

[My Implementation](http://pastebin.com/WydEKY86)

How would I go about implemented a non browser interface to add a song to a playlist? (Mind you this is python 3)

Comment: How would you expect to run the application if not through a web browser? 
Command Line? If that's the case, you would create the requests object in the `if __name__ == "__main__":` portion of the python module and send it off to the spotify playlist.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that could you throw me some references and examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to add a song to a playlist, you need the playlist's owner to grant access to your application, so you will need a web interface at some point to carry out this step.

It's important that you obtain the access token using the [Authorization Code Flow](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#authorization_code_flow) since that's how you will get an access token and a refresh token. Use that refresh token in your app to obtain [access tokens](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#request-access-token-from-refresh-token) without having the user to re-authorize your app.

So in brief:

1. Implement a web site that uses the Authorization Code. A user logs in and you obtain an access token and refresh token. Using the refresh token you will be able to generate access tokens without the user having to input their credentials.
2. Take the refresh token and include it in your script. Before making the request to add a track, obtain a fresh access token using the refresh token.

It's a bit cumbersome but that's the only way to use OAuth2 without exposing the user's username+password to an app.

Comment: I ended up porting spotipy for python 2.7 to python 3